# swift 3 http request for json file and inserting into fmdb

Tags: swift3, fmdb

I'm having trouble inserting data from the JSON file from my server.

I'm getting the error of

Failed to insert initial data into the database.
Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "s": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near "s": syntax error} near "s": syntax error

However, 9 of the data entries are inserted into the database before the error occurs and the app doesn't crash too. I'm wondering if it's a problem with the json file on the server or it's the code that I have. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I only started 2-3 months ago so perfectionists cut me some slack

```
    func insertMovieData() {
    if openDatabase() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://blahblahblah")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
                    var query = ""

                let jsonObj = JSON(json)
                    if jsonObj != JSON.null {
                        for (_, jsonObj) in jsonObj {
                            let movieTitle = jsonObj["subject"]
                            let movieCoverURL = jsonObj["message"]
                            print(movieTitle)

                            query += "insert into movies  values (null, '\(movieTitle)', '\(movieCoverURL)');"
                        }
                    }
                    if !self.database.executeStatements(query) {
                        print("Failed to insert initial data into the database.")
                        print(self.database.lastError(), self.database.lastErrorMessage())
                    }
                    else {
                        print(movies)
                    }

                self.database.close()
            }
                task.resume()
            }

    }
```